# Store the Disposable when subscribed to a Mono in database

Tags: spring, rx-java, rx-java2, project-reactor

I am currently exploring the [reactor-core](https://projectreactor.io). I am able to subscribe to a Mono and also save the disposable to handle the execution of the subscriber.

```
Mono<Object> task1 = Mono.just("Task1");
Mono<Object> task2 = Mono.just("Task2");
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
HashMap<Mono,Disposable> taskHandlerMap = new HashMap<>();
Disposable task1Handler = task1.delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5)).subscribe(
(Object x)->{
        System.out.println(x.toString() + "\t" + System.currentTimeMillis());
});
taskHandlerMap.put(task1,task1Handler);
Disposable task2Handler = task2.delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(10)).subscribe(
(Object x)->{
        System.out.println(x.toString() + "\t" + System.currentTimeMillis());
});
taskHandlerMap.put(task2,task2Handler);
```

I am able to dispose a scheduled task by using the handler map as follows.

```
taskHandlerMap.get(task2).dispose();
```

Can I save this taskHandlerMap in a database? Is yes, how can I save it. Else is there a better way to store the disposable created at subscription.

Comment: That makes no sense. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @akarnokd I want to store them so that I can dispose some scheduled tasks if required. For that I need to store them in some database.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. As if you'd want to store file handles in a database. Disposable objects refer to in-memory live flows, there is no way you can store them and recall them to point to the same object unless you keep a map in memory, which you wanted to store in the database...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as @akarnokd points out, a `Disposable` is merely a reference to a live computation, and it makes no sense to try and save it and restore it to/from a database.

It is kind of like if you submitted an long HTTP call to an `ExecutorService` and expected to be able to save the `Future` to the DB and somehow restore it... If the application stops, the HTTP call is gone anyway. If the application keeps on running, there's no need to keep the `Future` in a DB (you'd keep it in memory, with the same lifespan as the HTTP call).